# How to stop a form redirection after displaying an error message in PHP?

Tags: php, validation, submission

How do I avoid a form resubmission in the following instance - My HTML file has a form which sends the data to itself to be validated. Included in the same page, before the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag is a required PHP statement. This gets the contents of a file called `process.php` and checks the users data. If the data is incorrect then it successfully shows an error message. If the data is correct it sends an email. - This all works fine however if the user goes back 'presses the back arrow' and refreshes the page then it asks to re-send the data. How do I avoid this problem.

```
<?php require("inc/process.php"); end(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Page one</title>
 </head>
 <body>

   <div class="form-box">

   <!--Display error message PHP-->
   <?php
    if (isset($error_msg)) {
     $show_error = "<p class='error-message'>" . $error_msg . "</p>";
     echo strip_tags($show_error, '<p>');
    }
    ?>

    <form method="post" action="index.html">
     <input name="full-name" type="text">
     <input name="email" type="email">
    </form>

   </div> 


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can be wrong but this is a normal behavior. Instead of finding a work around this, why not implement a validation also in client side? The form will not be send to server if it's not valid. And if someone try to 'hack' your form validation, the server will fire the exception as it's already done. For example, you can add the attribute `required` to the `input` that's are required (like age)

Comment: Ok thats a good suggestion. How would I stop the form data being sent to the sever?

Comment: You don't have to 'stop' data from being send. The browser will manage that automatically for you. For example, you want all your fields to be filled except age. So you can try something like that on all your fields `<input name="First-name" class="first-name" type="text" placeholder="First name" required>//required added`. Concerning the field age, you can disabled it  `<input name="age" class="age" type="text" placeholder="Please leave blank" disabled> //disabled added`. More info about input tag here http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_input.asp

Comment: I would prefer not to use HTML validation because it can be altered by a user. This is a bit of a security risk.

Comment: no, because you also keep the validation on server side. Instead of sending invalid data to the server and send back an error. This will prevent invalid data from being send and if someone hack it, like I said in my first post, the server validation will prevent the form validation. It also user friendly because your users don't have to wait server response and they will see directly in the browser that the field is invalid. This is how modern website works. Anyway, it's just a suggestion, if you don't want to that, the decision is yours :)

Answer (score 0):

well its best to use jquery ajax, for example:

```
$("#FormID").submit(function(e) {

var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#FormID").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
     })

  // when the request is succesfull
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert(data); // show response from the php script.
  })

  // when an error occurs
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  });

e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form. (no redirection)

});
```